# Getting the query from a django Q() object

Tags: python, sql, django, django-q

I have a Django queryset where I have to use the `.extra(select=)` method, since I'm calculating a field that requires a `WHERE` statement subfilter.

I use this `WHERE` clause in a number of places, and I'd like to be obeying DRY (which is usually somewhat difficult when writing raw SQL).  I have written a statement using Django's `Q()` objects that I could reuse and add into the raw SQL.

I know that you can do `Queryset.query.__str__()` to get the equivalent SQL output--is there a way to do this with `Q` objects?

Comment: Where in the documentation does it say `QuerySet.query` gives you the raw SQL?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer--`QuerySet.query` as a command doesn't do anything, but if you have a queryset, you can call `.query.__str__()` on it and get the SQL statement back. "`QuerySet`" I was just using as a placeholder.